# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I know this has been asked on her before but I've tried any solution I can find and still no luck. I downloaded a portfolio template which has been working fine with npm start until the past couple days I now receive this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/justinlengvarsky/Desktop/Personal Portfolio/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/justinlengvarsky/Desktop/Personal Portfolio/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I then tried to do git init but receive an error that I don't have a start script in my json file. When I add the start script I receive this error:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-portfolio@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "personal-portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/LengvarskyJ/personal-portfolio.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/LengvarskyJ/personal-portfolio/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/LengvarskyJ/personal-portfolio#readme"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Uninstall and install node and npm again.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is try to delete the package.json file, and node_modules  and .git folder and to re-initialize everything (npm init --y and add all your dependencies) and git. And then try again.

Furthermore, if this does not work, just try updating/reinstalling node. Maybe something with your npm installation is not properly configured.